# Subindex out of interval (Error 9) when using a loop to delete rows with a certain string on it

Tags: string, vba, loops, rows

I have the following code aimed to delete rows which the first two letters of the string contained in column 3 are not "SW", for workhseets 2 and 3 of the workbook:

```
Sub Summrize()

Dim n As Integer
Dim i As Integer
Dim identif As String
Dim idftl As String
Dim ws As Worksheet

For n = 2 To 3
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(i)
    With ws
        For i = 200 To 1 Step -1

        identif = .Cells(i, 3).Value
        idftl = Left(identif, 2)

        If Not idftl = "SW" Then
        .Rows(i & ":" & i).Delete
    End If

    Next i
    End With
Next n

End Sub
```

It stops in the beginning of the second loop, (this is `For i = 200 To 1 Step -1`) and I get the error:

> Error 9: Subindex out of interval

I've tried a lot of things but can't reach the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you accidentally used i instead of n in the following line:

```
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(i)
```

i has not yet been declared at this point. Thus, it defaults to 0, and you do not have a sheet number 0.

Answer (score 1):

It could help you to set a bookmark and watch View/Locals window or also hover variables to see current value.

Comment: Would you tell me how can I find info about hover variables?

Comment: I mean flyover with the mouse pointer during breakpoint and it displays the value

Answer (score 0):

Should be:
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(n)

instead of:
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(i)